# How to get user firstname from Facebook using access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get some facebook current user basic information.

Here is my code. (It's Oracle PL/SQL)

```
    URL := 'http://graphm-facebook.maxapex.ws/me?fields(id,name,email)&access_token=' || Token;                      
    Method := 'GET';
    Response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => URL, p_http_method => Method);
```

But I'm getting the html answer : 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

I'm sure it's not related to any service unavailability. Because when I run the following command, it works successfully.

```
    URL := 'http://graphm-facebook.maxapex.ws/me?access_token=' || Token;
```

Can anyone help please ? Thanks.

Comment: What weird API URL is that, `graphm-facebook.maxapex.ws`? That is not the official address of the Graph API - looks like some third-party wrapper someone build around it? (I wonder if that’s even legal ...)

Comment: Check the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/